# ASP .NET CORE MVC save information from a JSON with multiple data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I send a JSON through $.ajax() to an mvc controller where i'd like to save those records for a given report.

reportRecords are saved in a table with fields:

```
id, Reportid, ItemId, CategoryId, UnitCost, Revenue, Units
```

I need to update only UnitCost, Revenue, Units for the given id.

The JSON is an aggregate of data from different entities collected from an HTML table.

My JSON (where id is the id in the reportRecords table):

```
[
{"id":"1","category":"xxx","item":"yyy","packing":"zzz","units":"35","unitCost":"45","unitRevenue":"65","unitMargin":"20","marginPercent":"44.44","totCost":"1575","totRevenue":"2275","totMargin":"700,00","marginWeight":"80.65 %"},
{"id":"2","category":"xxx","item":"yyy","packing":"zzz","units":"56","unitCost":"32","unitRevenue":"35","unitMargin":"3","marginPercent":"9.37","totCost":"1792","totRevenue":"1960","totMargin":"168,00","marginWeight":"19.35 %"}
]
```

My C# EF class:

```
public class ReportRecord
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Report Report { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Category Category{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public float? UnitCost { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public float? Revenue { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Units { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1) to figure out how to deserialize json data. FYI, float is not an appropriate data type for something representing money because it has precision issues.

Comment: I can't tell if your problem is that you don't know how to save the JSON, you don't know how to read the JSON, you don't understand serialization, or you don't know how to modify individual properties in a class while leaving the others intact.  An extended tutorial is beyond the scope of this site, so *make your question more specific.*

Comment: Thank you guys for your time, i'm very new both to C# and to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Crowcoder What's the correct type for money ? Where can i find info on those precision issue?

Comment: @RobertHarvey All of the ones you cited

Comment: You can read about floating point number precision and the decimal type [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#838-the-decimal-type)

Answer (score 0):

How i solved:

I had to get JSON data, pick the ones i needed and save the involved entities. I solved it this way:

```
// POST: Reports/Asave/5
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Asave(int? id)
{
    var json = Request.Query["json"][0];

    var jsonAsArray = JArray.Parse(json);

    float reportTotalCost = 0;
    float reportTotalRevenue = 0;

    foreach (var item in jsonAsArray)
    {
        reportTotalRevenue += item.Value<float>("totRevenue");
        reportTotalCost += item.Value<float>("totCost");

        var reportRecord = _context.ReportRecords.Find(item.Value<int>("id"));
        reportRecord.Revenue = item.Value<float>("unitRevenue");

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    var report = _context.Reports.Find(id);

    report.Revenue = reportTotalRevenue;
    
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { code = 200, result = "success" });
}
```

It works but i think it might be prone to side effects.

Comment: You should use await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); instead of your synchronous call. And as mentioned earlier, float might not be the best decision for things related to money. Also you might want to check out [DTOs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) and why to use them.